# Existence of regular $n$-gon whose vertices are arbitrarily close to integer coordinates

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, polygons

I'm self-studying these days about polytopes and I came with this question. I don't know if it's true or not.

> Let $\alpha_1$, $\ldots$, $\alpha_n$ angles of convex $n$-gon, $n\not=4$. Prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a convex $n$-gon with vertices in  $\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $|\frac{\pi}{n}(n-2)-\alpha_i|<\varepsilon$

I have thought of two possible alternatives, one of them is Dirichlet Approximation and the other is showing that $SO(2,\mathbb{Q})$ is dense in $SO(2)$.

Comment: If $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ are the angles of a regular $n$-gon, shouldn't $|\frac\pi n(n-2) - \alpha_i|$ be $0$ for all $i$? (I mean, I'm confident that's not what you intended, but I'm not sure what you did intend.)

Comment: And there is no regular $n$-gon with vertices in $\mathbb Z^2$ if $n=5$, for example.

Comment: My mistake, I wrote something bad

Comment: Can you add to your question some examples of polygons you've proven this statement for, along with the proofs? That context would help us answer your question.

Comment: @RobertIsrael In fact there is no regular $n$-gon with vertices in $\Bbb{Z^2}$ for any $n>2$ other than $n=4$. [Here is a nice animation](https://youtu.be/sDfzCIWpS7Q?t=775) illustrating why. A detailed explanation is given from [7:10](https://youtu.be/sDfzCIWpS7Q?t=430) onwards, I suggest speeding up the video a bit.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Let $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ be the vertices of a regular $n$-gon in $\Bbb{R}^2$. For each $p_i$ take a point $q_i\in\Bbb{Q}^2$ that is sufficiently close to $p_i$ (depending on $\varepsilon$). Now scale up all the coordinates of the $q_i$ to get vertices in $\Bbb{Z}^2$ without changing the angles $\alpha_i$. [This video](https://youtu.be/sDfzCIWpS7Q?t=289) illustrates the idea for $n=3$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was also thinking about that idea, however I can't think of a way to formalize it. On the other hand, showing that $SO_2(\mathbb{Q})$ is dense in $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$ could be an indirect way to approach the problem?

Comment: All you need to do in order to formalize it is to show that an angle $\angle ABC$ is a continuous function of the coordinates of $A$, $B$, and $C$, so that sufficiently small changes in those coordinates won't affect the angle by more than $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=6$ it's easy.  Start with a triangle.  Multiply its sides by $3$.  Trisect the tripled sides and render the trisection points as vertices of a hexagon.  The hexagon will have three pairs of parallel and congruent sides.